# "rake adcenter-client" giving error-RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rake, rake-task

I am using adcenter-client gem for using microsoft's adcenter api in my RoR-2.3.8 application.
I am using ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
After installing the gem adcenter-client -v=7.0.3 I tried to execute `rake adcenter-client` but I got the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'adcenter-client'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `invoke_task'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'   
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33  
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'  
/usr/local/bin/rake:19
```

Can anyone please give me some suggestion to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

Even it is mentioned in [GitHub](https://github.com/bleechack/adcenter-client) to run `rake adcenter-client`, but it doesn't require. Code will work properly without this rake task too.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to run this rake task if you checkout the code directly. When working with the Gem it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for reply but I already got the solution. Thank You for reply.